# Attribute Route is not working properly and the specified URL returns HTTP 404 Not Found?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

With respect to this *Attibute route* when i run application i am getting HTTP 404 Not Found result **why?**.

```
[Route("custom/route/{id}/{name}")]
public ActionResult Student(int id, string name)
{
   return Content(string.Format("id = {0} & name = {1}", id, name)); 
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Are you applied `MapMvcAttributeRoutes()` method inside route configuration? Check if the attribute routing is enabled first.

Comment: Do you have the Route attribute at the controller? Please post that code too.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your RouteConfig.cs looks something like this:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection Routes)
    {
        Routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.ashx/{*pathInfo}");
        Routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        Routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            namespaces: new string[] { "YourControllerNamespace.Controllers" },
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );           
    }
}
```

Please pay attention to **namespace** parameter in **Routes.MapRoute**